# How to integrate "old spring mvc controllers with jsp" and "vaadin7 ui" together

Tags: spring-mvc, vaadin

I am trying to integrate vaadin with my spring mvc application.
I have a some url with jsp files that spring mvc controller use them
For example : 
              mysite.com/spring/
              mysite.com/spring/examples
              mysite.com/spring/examples/1.jsp

I want to add vaadin in this path:
              mysite.com/vaadin/MainUI

here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
      metadata-complete="true">

  <display-name>vaadin-spring</display-name>

  <!-- Turn off productionMode (off by default). Setting productionMode=true disables 
       debug features. In when this is off, you can show debug window by adding ?debug to 
       your application URL. Always set this true in production environment. -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
    <description>Vaadin production mode</description>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>vaadin-spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.practice.vaadin_spring.VaadinSpringDemoApplication</param-value>
      <description>Vaadin application class to start</description>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>vaadin-spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/vaadin/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>vaadin-spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/VAADIN/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- spring -->
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
            <param-value>local</param-value>
        </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here is my spring main controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "{jspFile}")
    public String map(@PathVariable String jspFile) throws IOException {
        return jspFile;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String map1() throws IOException {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

Here is working example (after fix) in github
https://github.com/prilia/IntegrationSpringMvcVaadinUI

Comment: this looks like a class path issue. Are you deploying some JAR files with your application that are also present in / should only come from your Tomcat `lib` directory? Easiest way to find out is run your server with additional option `-verbose:class` and inspect output to determine what JAR holds these invalid entries.

Comment: I remove all jars from lib and there is no error now, but the spring servlet is not mapped --> PageNotFound [WARN] No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/springMvcTest/spring] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Comment: What is the full URL you are accessing? `web.xml` has a servlet mapping for `/spring` and your `MainController` class is configured for a further mapping for `/spring`. So I don't see where the `/springMvcTest` part from your error message is supposed to go. Shouldn't it be `/spring/spring` or something like that?

Comment: same errors -> DispatcherServlet [INFO] FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization completed in 346 ms
PageNotFound [WARN] No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/springMvcTest/spring/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
PageNotFound [WARN] No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/springMvcTest/spring/spring] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Comment: yes, it's a web application root -> http://localhost:9090/springMvcTest/spring/spring/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68919/discussion-between-geert3-and-prilia).

Comment: Apart from the Spring-related problems you have (they seem to come from some misconfiguration in your Spring setup, but I'm not really knowledgable about Spring MVC, so I can't help you there), what exactly do you mean with your original question? In which way do you want to run Spring MVC and Vaadin together? Shall they run side by side, each with its own context, or do you want to integrate a Vaadin UI on a Spring MVC page?

Comment: I want to integrate Vaadin UI with Spring context, but I want to save my old jsp that rendered with Spring MVC controllers.

Comment: has the addition of the Vaadin servlet tags broke your project or have you made modifications somewhere else? I mean, if you comment away the vaadin servlet in web.xml does all run fine?

Comment: I did github for example, please take a look - https://github.com/prilia/IntegrationSpringMvcVaadinUI

Comment: thanks, i'll take a look and tell you if i find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some tries i've ended up with a JSP compile exception, which i believe is reasonable since you provided a test example on github.
So far here's what i've done:

web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

MainController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController { ...
```

spring-servlet.xml i've added

```
<bean name="spring" class="org.nli.deposit.controller.MainController" />
```

Now seems it resolves the url:

http://localhost:8080/springMvcTest/ goes to JSPs

http://localhost:8080/springMvcTest/vaadin goes to Vaadin

it just crashes during JSP compilation, but that's a whole another question.
Try on your complete project and let me know!